# Quoting or italicizing latex `glossaries` package acronyms on first use (full term only)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Suppose in my `.tex` document I invoke for the first time `\gls{ip}`, which based on my definition results in the text:

> Internet Protocol (IP)

Is there any way to quote (or italicize) just the long form of the term, to achieve a result like:

> "Internet Protocol" (IP)

I know using something like `''\gls{ip}''` I can achieve a result like:

> "Internet Protocol (IP)"

...but in this case both the the long form of the term and the acronym end up inside of the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is not much information on the setup of the glossary, I used some standard command to enquote the long term description.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newcommand{\doquotes}[1]{\enquote{#1}}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{IP}{%
  name={IP},
  description={\doquotes{Internet Protocol}}
}%


\begin{document}
 \glsaddall

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Compile with

> pdflatex foo.tex ; makeglossaries -o foo.gls foo.glo

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use LaTeX quotes, e.g.

```
\newacronym{ip}{IP}{``Internet Protocol''}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ip}{IP}{``Internet Protocol''}

\begin{document}
First use \gls{ip} 

Second use \gls{ip}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create a new acronym style. You can do so by writing something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newacronymstyle{enquote-long-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \enquote{\glsentrylong{##1}##2}\space
   (\glsentryshort{##1})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \enquote{\Glsentrylong{##1}##2}\space
   (\glsentryshort{##1})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \enquote{\glsentrylongpl{##1}##2}\space
   (\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \enquote{\Glsentrylongpl{##1}##2}\space
   (\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
  }%
}

\setacronymstyle{enquote-long-short}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ip}{IP}{Internet Protocol}

\begin{document}
First use of \gls{ip}, second use of \gls{ip}.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: First use of "Internet Protocol" (IP), second use of IP.]

Comment: I think this is the best answer since it separates the style from the entry definitions. It will make it a lot easier if you decide to change the style at a later date. (Assuming you want this style for all abbreviations rather than one specific entry.)